# Make http DELETE request with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, nsurlsession

I'm trying to make an http DELETE request using NSURLSession, but it's not completely working. The server deletes the resource, but the NSURLSession method dataTaskWithRequest: completionHandler: returns a time out error after waiting for the specified timeout.

I am not using NSURLConnection because it is deprecated.

Of the NSURLSession methods to use, I chose dataTaskWithRequest because it is most similar to the method I use for http GET: dataTaskWithUrl: completionHandler. The methods beginning with "uploadTask" and "downloadTask" don't seem appropriate for a DELETE, but downloadTaskWithRequest: completionHandler: 'worked' in the same way as the dataTask method above. The server deleted the resource, but the method returned a time out error.

Here is the code:

```
+(void)httpDelete: (NSString*)url completionHandler: (void(^)(id, NSError*))complete 
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *urlSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSMutableDictionary* dictionaryAdditionalHeaders = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString* stringBearerToken = @"...";
    NSString* stringApiKey = @"...";

    [dictionaryAdditionalHeaders setObject:stringBearerToken forKey:@"Authorization"];
    [dictionaryAdditionalHeaders setObject:stringApiKey forKey:@"x-api-key"];
    [dictionaryAdditionalHeaders setObject:@"application/json" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    [dictionaryAdditionalHeaders setObject:@0 forKey:@"Content-Length"];

    [urlSessionConfiguration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders: dictionaryAdditionalHeaders];

    NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: urlSessionConfiguration delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSMutableURLRequest* mutableUrlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:5];
    [mutableUrlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"DELETE"];

    [[urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:mutableUrlRequest completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error)
    {
        if(error != nil)
        {
            complete(response, error);
        }
        else
        {
            complete(response, nil);
        }
   }] resume];
}
```

Using Postman, the DELETE call returns with a 204 immediately.

Am I using NSURLSession correctly for a delete request?

Comment: time-out error is a backend issue. Unless you get response or hit the failure block, we never where the issue is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the Amazon API Gateway incorrectly sends a Content-Length header with a 204 response.  They added the issue to their backlog March 21, 2016 according to [this AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=706771). When I increased the timeout interval of the NSMutableURLRequest to a ridiculous 300 seconds, the dataTaskWithRequest method returns with a real response instead of timing out.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an error with NSURLSession - it means that your request is actually timing out. That means that there's an error on the back-end (maybe it's not reaching your server at all?)

Also, I've found these issues much easier to debug using a third-party framework to send my HTTP requests. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is a really good one.

Comment: The request reaches the server and the server deletes the resource.